# How to convert properly rst format to any other fornat via pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

I've tried to convert with this command:

```
pandoc -s -S --toc -f rst -t docx document.rst -o document.docx
```

But in output my document lost any internal links and automatic content. Also, I've tried to convert rst to html and output contained automatic content, but lost some other features.
I solved problem by converting via rst2html.py script, and from html format it easily converted to docx via pandoc. So, I wonder how to make this via pure pandoc? Is it possible in general?

Comment: It will help if you post your input or a minimum example which highlights the problem.

Comment: Could you please, tell me where I can put document with size of 50K?

Comment: It might be better if you make a post to the [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) mailing list as there will be more people who can help and you can attach files.

Comment: Thank you. One guy answered, that they still did not add full support for all restructured text features.

Comment: If there is a specific feature you would like then feel free to request it on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues). I'm not too familiar with the input format so can't comment on how quickly it could be implemented.